# PHP: How to replace text after a specific word?

Tags: php, replace

I have a string that will be executed as a query but it have `between` functions in this way:

```
BETWEEN '2019-01-01 AND 2019-01-31'
```

But I need to replace it with this so PostgreSQL can understand it:

```
BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-31'
```

Comment: `BETWEEN '2019-01-01 AND 2019-01-31'` isn't a valid query for any engine as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0):

I solved with:

```
$string = str_replace(" AND ", "' AND '", $string);
```